# Creating line segment lists from x,y lists in Python

Tags: python

I want to coordinate data for rectangles is given in two lists (e.g.):

```
x = [1, 8, 9, 4]  
y = [2, 3, 6, 7]
```

I want to create a list of the line segment endpoints representing the rectangles.  It would be ideal if the list was in the form:

```
segment_endpoints = [((1, 2), (8, 3)), ((8, 3), (9, 6)), ((9, 6), (4, 7)), ((4, 7), (1, 2))]
```

My attempt:

```
vertices = zip(x, y)  
segment_endpoints = zip(vertices, vertices[1:] + [vertices[0]])
```

But Python will not let me zip a zipped object.

Surely there is an easy way to do this.  New to programming.  New to stackoverflow.

Comment: When I run your code in *Python* 2.7. I don't get any errors. What version of *Python*, and what error do you get?

Comment: I dont get errors too. This is my output `[((1, 2), (8, 3)), ((8, 3), (9, 6)), ((9, 6), (4, 7)), ((4, 7), (1, 2))]
[Finished in 0.0s]` using Python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3 when using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) you need to  use `list(zip())`:

```
In [10]: vertices = list(zip(x, y))

In [11]: list(zip(vertices, vertices[1:] + [vertices[0]]))
Out[11]: [((1, 2), (8, 3)), ((8, 3), (9, 6)), ((9, 6), (4, 7)), ((4, 7), (1, 2))]
```

In `python3` `zip` returns an iterator as opposed to a list in `python2` so you need to use the `list(zip())` syntax.

Comment: Ah, this is good to know; I mostly code in Python 2.7.x, so have not encountered this yet.